# Display files without block the app in php

Tags: php, apache2, readfile

I'm serving a php app on Apache2. In a function I simply want to display media, using php script instead of hosting the medias in a public folder on the server.

This is because I want to be able to add functions to control the permissions from the logged in user later, and check file extensions etc first.

I've tried **fpassthru** and **readfile** and both functions completely blocks the application. Especially when there's a video > 10mb.

**Here's a version of the code:**

display_file.php?filename=foo.jpg

```
if (empty($_GET['filename']))
{
    die(http_response_code(500)):
}

$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$extension = file_extension($filename); // .jpg|.mp4 etc
$mime = mime($ext); // get mine_type
$uri = '/foo/bar/'.$filename;


// Only allow sertain extensions
if (!in_array($ext, ALLOWED_FILE_EXTENSIONS)) // ['jpg','png','mp4'...]
{
    die(http_response_code(403));
}

// File doesn't exist
if (!file_exists($uri))
{
    die(http_response_code(404));
}

$size = filesize($uri);
$start = 0;
$end = $size - 1;
$time = filemtime($uri);
$expires = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $time + (60 * 60));
$modified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $time);

//$fp = fopen($uri, 'rb');

header('Pragma: cache');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=31536000');
header('Expires: '.$expires);
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Length: '.$size);
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header('Last-Modified: '.$modified);

//fpassthru($fp);
readfile($uri);
```

If I instead display the files direct through the public folder using Apache2, the app won't be blocked.

Is there any other way to serve/display files with php user check, extensions etc. without blocking the entire app?

Comment: For video and audio you probably need to research how to stream them using php rather than reading the entire file at once. I imagine you can google it already

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis/description is not clear. What do you mean by "block the app"? How did you measure this?

I suspect what is happenning here is that the *session* is blocked, not the app although there could be an issue with the content file being locked.

The code you've show us would not block the session - there is no session. But the code is clearly incomplete. Adding a `session_write_close()` before `readfile()` would resolve (or use a non-blocking session handler).

Locking of the content file is less likely - but you didn't tell us what operating system this is running on so we can't tell you how to investigate further.